# Red ear slider female

Tags: health, turtles

Red ear slider 18 yr female, for the first time, has a black tube extended, at times 1 & 1/2 ins. Long, under her tail w/ 4 items gathered at its end. Are they eggs & what can we do to help get them released?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Red flesh coming out my turtle's tail](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9295/red-flesh-coming-out-my-turtles-tail)