# Which light is good for aquarium turtles, UVA, UVB, UVC?

Tags: aquarium, turtles, lighting

In continuation of my question [Do aquarium turtles require basking everyday?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18183/do-aquarium-turtles-require-basking-everyday)

1. I will purchase a UV bulb for turtles but which one should I purchase UVA, UVB or UVC?
2. How much distance should I keep between basking area (water surface) and bulb? I don't want their soft skin gets burned. 
   As of now the distance between the water surface and single CFL (8 W) is almost 12 to 15 inches.

Comment: do not use UVC it is dangerous to all living things it is used to sterilize water and surgical equipment so DO NOT USE UVC on any living things unless you want to kill it.

Comment: Should it be UVB or UVA? How much distance should I keep?

Comment: uva+uvb, you can read the linked Q&A to understand how&why it do cover this fully.